# Show/hide multiple popup when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a Pen on Show/hide multiple popup : https://codepen.io/Volabos/pen/BGdBKw

As you see, here we have 3 sections for `2016`, `2017`, and `2018`. The goal is when user clicks on them different windows will slip-up displaying different information.

My implementation works fine for `2016`. In that case, a Pop-up window showing `PART 01` will open. However, for 2017, I have implemented just same logic, but failed to show `PART 02`.

Could someone point me exactly what went wrong for `2017`?

```js
var toggle = document.getElementById('toggle_Y1');
var slider = document.querySelector('.slider_Y1');
var toggle1 = document.getElementById('toggle_Y11');


toggle.addEventListener('click', toggleSlider, false);
toggle1.addEventListener('click', toggleSlider, false);


function toggleSlider() {
  if (slider.classList.contains('opened_Y1')) {
    slider.classList.remove('opened_Y1');
    slider.classList.add('closed_Y1');
  } else {
    slider.classList.remove('closed_Y1');
    slider.classList.add('opened_Y1');

  }
}


var toggle_2 = document.getElementById('toggle_Y2');
var slider_2 = document.querySelector('.slider_Y2');
var toggle1_2 = document.getElementById('toggle_Y21');


toggle_2.addEventListener('click', toggleSlider_2, false);
toggle1_2.addEventListener('click', toggleSlider_2, false);


function toggleSlider_2() {
  if (slider_2.classList.contains('opened_Y2')) {
    slider_2.classList.remove('opened_Y2');
    slider_2.classList.add('closed_Y2');
  } else {
    slider_2.classList.remove('closed_Y2');
    slider_2.classList.add('opened_Y2');

  }
}
```

```css
.content_EQ_Announcement_Y {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
  width: 33.2%;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .0);
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Y1 {
  border-right: 0px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.EQ_Announcement_Y1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  height: 292px;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .0);
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.slider_Y1,
.slider_Y2 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .0);
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  z-index: 200;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform .3s ease;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform .3s ease;
  transition: transform .3s ease;
}

.slider_Y1.opened_Y1,
.slider_Y2.opened_Y2 {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0%);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, 0%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 0%);
  transform: translate(0, 0%);
  background: #fff;
}

.slider_Y1.closed_Y1,
.slider_Y2.closed_Y2 {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 100%);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, 100%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 100%);
  transform: translate(0, 100%);
}

#toggle_Y11,
#toggle_Y21 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .0);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>


<div class="EQ_Announcement_Y1">
  <div class='content_EQ_Announcement_Y'>
    <div id='toggle_Y1'>2016</div>
  </div>
  <div class='content_EQ_Announcement_Y'>
    <div id='toggle_Y2'>2017</div>
  </div>
  <div class='content_EQ_Announcement_Y'>
    <div id='toggle_Y3'>2018</div>
  </div>

  <div class="slider_Y1 closed_Y1">
    <div id='toggle_Y11'>
      PART 01
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider_Y2 closed_Y2">
    <div id='toggle_Y21'>
      PART 02
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In the future, please include your code *in the question itself*. I've edited your question to include it as a runnable snippet.

Comment: So I switched the order of your HTML and the part 2 appears, the part 1 does not. The first slider is stacked on top of the other slider, so its blocking its ability to come into the fold.

My recommendation would be to place your sliders within a parent div. Instead of sliding up the individual slides, slide up the container but still do the transformations on the specific element you want to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Transform `.slider_Y2.opened_Y2` to `-100%`**

```js
var toggle = document.getElementById('toggle_Y1');
var slider = document.querySelector('.slider_Y1');
var toggle1 = document.getElementById('toggle_Y11');


toggle.addEventListener('click', toggleSlider, false);
toggle1.addEventListener('click', toggleSlider, false);


function toggleSlider() {
  if (slider.classList.contains('opened_Y1')) {
    slider.classList.remove('opened_Y1');
    slider.classList.add('closed_Y1');
  } else {
    slider.classList.remove('closed_Y1');
    slider.classList.add('opened_Y1');

  }
}


var toggle_2 = document.getElementById('toggle_Y2');
var slider_2 = document.querySelector('.slider_Y2');
var toggle1_2 = document.getElementById('toggle_Y21');


toggle_2.addEventListener('click', toggleSlider_2, false);
toggle1_2.addEventListener('click', toggleSlider_2, false);


function toggleSlider_2() {
  if (slider_2.classList.contains('opened_Y2')) {
    slider_2.classList.remove('opened_Y2');
    slider_2.classList.add('closed_Y2');
  } else {
    slider_2.classList.remove('closed_Y2');
    slider_2.classList.add('opened_Y2');

  }
}
```

```css
.content_EQ_Announcement_Y {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
  width: 33.2%;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .0);
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Y1 {
  border-right: 0px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.EQ_Announcement_Y1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  height: 292px;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .0);
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.slider_Y1,
.slider_Y2 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .0);
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  z-index: 200;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform .3s ease;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform .3s ease;
  transition: transform .3s ease;
}

.slider_Y1.opened_Y1 {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0%);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, 0%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 0%);
  transform: translate(0, 0%);
  background: #fff;
}

.slider_Y1.closed_Y1,
.slider_Y2.closed_Y2 {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 100%);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, 100%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 100%);
  transform: translate(0, 100%);
}

.slider_Y2.opened_Y2 {
  background: white;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -100%);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, -100%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -100%);
  transform: translate(0, -100%);
}

#toggle_Y11,
#toggle_Y21 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .0);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>


<div class="EQ_Announcement_Y1">
  <div class='content_EQ_Announcement_Y'>
    <div id='toggle_Y1'>2016</div>
  </div>
  <div class='content_EQ_Announcement_Y'>
    <div id='toggle_Y2'>2017</div>
  </div>
  <div class='content_EQ_Announcement_Y'>
    <div id='toggle_Y3'>2018</div>
  </div>

  <div class="slider_Y1 closed_Y1">
    <div id='toggle_Y11'>
      PART 01
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider_Y2 closed_Y2">
    <div id='toggle_Y21'>
      PART 02
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.slider_Y1 height = 100%  ===> distance from top = 100%
.slider_Y2.opened_Y2 height = 100% + .slider_Y1 height  === > distance from top = 200%


.slider_Y2.opened_Y2 {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -100%);
    -moz-transform: translate(0, -100%);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, -100%);
    transform: translate(0, -100%);
    background: #fff;
}
```